# Change CSS styling with javascript depending on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I currently have CSS styling that gives `background-color` and `padding` to the "Previous" and "Next" buttons on the product pages of my website.

The problem is on the first page of the product results, the styling for the "Previous" button is still showing, even though their is no "previous" button for the first page.

How do use javascript or jquery to send a conditional statement changing the styling for that button to be invisible on the first page?

```
#SearchStyle {
    color: white;
    background-color: #3498db;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }

#SearchStyle2 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #3498db;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }

.CategoryPagination {
    color: #075899;
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="CategoryPagination">
        <div class="FloatLeft" id="SearchStyle"></div>
        <div class="FloatRight" id="SearchStyle2">
        <a href="http://www.catholictothemax.com/products.html? 
         sort=featured&amp;page=2">Next</a></div>
```

**You can also see the issue on the page here:**
http://www.catholictothemax.com/search.php?search_query=dog+tags

Comment: You can start by learning jQuery :)

Comment: What framework are you using to build your web app? We need more information.

Comment: I am working with the BigCommerce CMS. So the code currently looks like this:

Comment: `<div class="CategoryPagination">
<div class="FloatLeft" id="SearchStyle"></div>
<div class="FloatRight" id="SearchStyle2"><a href="http://www.catholictothemax.com/categories/catholic-apparel/catholic-apparel-accessories.html?sort=featured&amp;page=2">Next »</a></div>`

Comment: programmatically speaking, how do you know whether the current page is the first page of results or not? are you reading the url, or parsing the text of a certain element on the page, or is it stored in a variable, or some other method?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow has a valid point here, regardless of the styling issue, how do you get the current page ? Because I can bet you that this issue will happen on the last page too, but on the opposite (next) button. I have already provided an answer, but it would improve the answer you're gonna get if you gave us this information.

Comment: the only way to know whether the first page is the first page of results is through running a jquery script. that's really all i know. my knowledge of jquery is frankly very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery to hide the div if there's nothing in it.

```
if($('#FloatLeft').html() == ''){
    $('#FloatLeft').remove();
}
```

This will only work assuming your next and previous buttons post back to the server. If all your content is static, then use this instead:

//this requires you change the css classes like I explain below

```
$('.searchButton').on('click',function(){

    if($('#FloatLeft').html() == ''){
        $('#left').css('display','none');
    } else {
       $('#FloatLeft').css('display','block');
    }

}
```

edit

p.s.

Why do you have two `css` classes that do the same thing? Clean that up to one for readability. If you created two because the second element wasn't having styles applied to it, that's because you used `id` instead of `class`. `id` is unique, and will only target the first element it matches with that `id`. `#` is used for `id`, `.` is used for `class`.

```
.searchButton {
    color: white;
    background-color: #3498db;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

<div class="FloatLeft searchButton"></div>
<div class="FloatRight searchButton"> <a> whatever </a> </div>
```

Comment: one button has to float right and the other has to float left.

Comment: @abednabir Sure, that's fine. But the code to make the buttons float either way is not contained within those styles. Might as well make them one. Seems like the `FloatLeft` class is the one applying the `float` style, no?

Comment: I tried the first code bit and had no results. Not sure what I am supposed to put in here: **if(conditional that triggers whether FloatLeft is empty or not){**

Comment: @abednabir The `FloatLeft` class does not contain an `<a>` tag in it. This is because you are on the first page and there is no previous. You must perform some type of action to go between pages, for example clicking the search buttons. If that's the case, then you can replace that if statement with that click event listener. I'll update my code.

Comment: I need to have the function run on page load.

Comment: @abednabir Then you can just use my first example. The one that `remove`s the element entirely. If it's not working, put it inside a `$(document).ready(function() {     here     });`

Comment: I clicked the checkmark. That's all that needs to be done correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use `addClass` and `removeClass` methods.

```
if(condition) {
  $(element).addClass('class1');
  $(element).removeClass('class2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It still shows up because of its `padding: 10px;` !

You can either remove the padding completely, in which case the styling of the buttons gets messed up a little bit, but they disappear when there is no content in them, or determine somehow when these buttons are empty (maybe with javascript or jquery), and THEN either set them to `display:none;` so that they do not show up no matter what styling they have, or just remove the padding on that button.

The particular class that has the padding is the `<div class="FloatRight"`, and `<div class="FloatLeft"` so you should target it with something like: `.FloatRight { padding: 0; }` OR `.FloatRight { display: none; }` // whatever you choose!

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do it would be to:

1. Add a class to the body element using jQuery
2. Style the search section based on body class

You can add a class to the body like this:

```
var $body = $('body');
if (condition) {
    $body.addClass('different-page')
}
```

Then, in your CSS:

```
.search-style {
    color: white;
    background-color: #3498db;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.different-page .search-style {
    background-color: #3498db;
}
```

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="CategoryPagination">
    <div class="FloatLeft search-style"></div>
    <div class="FloatRight search-style">
        <a href="http://www.catholictothemax.com/products.html? sort=featured&amp;page=2">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because you would be using the same class `search-style`, there is no need to be redundant and repeat the CSS styles. You would only need to override one value, the background colour.

You should also avoid using both `id` and `class` selectors in CSS as you can run into CSS specificity issues.